# Hadoop reduce shuffle merge in memory

Tags: performance, hadoop, shuffle, reduce

I'm having some performance issues with Reduce Merge phase and I wonder if someone can take a look. I have a 6 GB dataset (text), evenly distributed on the cluster, The dataset has two keys that I then GroupBy into two reducers (I'm using cascading). So each reducer has 3GB of data. I give each reducer 12 GB of memory, but I'm still seeing a 20 minute merge phase.

Two questions: Shouldn't this merge be done entirely in memory (if I have 12 GB of Heap). Even without an in memory merge, 20 minutes seems like way way too long to merge 3GB, especially with 12 disks(JBOD) and 12 cores on a node. I'm wondering if I'm writing the partial merge data to the wrong place (HDFS, vs local?).

the MAPRFS_BYTES_READ, and MAPRFS_BYTES_WRITTEN are interesting. The initial dataset is 6GB (which it shows in the Map column). Somehow sorting increases it to 17GB, which seems odd. Then in the reduce Phase it's reading 23GB from MapRfs, and writing 17GB. Should the reduce phase merge data be written to MapRFS or to the local FS? WHy would the size grow so much over the initial dataset (no compression is used, it's straight text)

---

```
    Counter     Map     Reduce  Total
Job Counters    Aggregate execution time of mappers(ms)     0   0   29,887,359
Launched reduce tasks   0   0   2
Rack-local map tasks    0   0   4
Launched map tasks  0   0   353
Data-local map tasks    0   0   311
cascading.flow.SliceCounters    Read_Duration   329,399     366,004     695,403
Tuples_Read     252,000,000     67,896,295  319,896,295
Tuples_Written  252,000,000     0   252,000,000
Process_End_Time    476,294,761,317,139     0   476,294,761,317,139
Write_Duration  2,713,840   0   2,713,840
Process_Begin_Time  476,294,753,764,176     2,698,557,228,678   478,993,310,992,854
FileSystemCounters  MAPRFS_BYTES_READ   6,651,978,400   21,721,014,791  28,372,993,191
MAPRFS_BYTES_WRITTEN    17,044,716,578  17,044,701,398  34,089,417,976
FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN  19,046,005  107,748     19,153,753
Map-Reduce Framework    Map input records   252,000,000     0   252,000,000
Reduce shuffle bytes    0   16,980,659,887  16,980,659,887
Spilled Records     252,000,000     0   252,000,000
Map output bytes    16,540,701,046  0   16,540,701,046
CPU_MILLISECONDS    18,861,020  7,640,360   26,501,380
Map input bytes     6,644,947,675   0   6,644,947,675
Combine input records   0   0   0
SPLIT_RAW_BYTES     97,428  0   97,428
Reduce input records    0   67,896,295  67,896,295
Reduce input groups     0   2   2
Combine output records  0   0   0
PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES   324,852,019,200     15,041,486,848  339,893,506,048
Reduce output records   0   0   0
VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES    626,863,038,464     26,729,230,336  653,592,268,800
Map output records  252,000,000     0   252,000,000
GC time elapsed (ms)    1,568,523   76,636  1,645,159
cascading.flow.StepCounters     Tuples_Read     252,000,000     0   252,000,000
```

---

```
name    value
fs.s3n.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem
mapreduce.heartbeat.100 1000
mapred.task.cache.levels    2
hadoop.tmp.dir  /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}
hadoop.native.lib   true
map.sort.class  org.apache.hadoop.util.QuickSort
mapreduce.jobtracker.recovery.dir   /var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/recovery
mapreduce.heartbeat.1000    10000
ipc.client.idlethreshold    4000
mapred.system.dir   /var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/system
mapreduce.cluster.reduce.userlog.retain-size    10485760
mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.hours  0
io.skip.checksum.errors false
fs.default.name maprfs:///
mapred.cluster.reduce.memory.mb -1
mapred.child.tmp    ./tmp
fs.har.impl.disable.cache   true
mapred.jobtracker.jobhistory.lru.cache.size 5
mapred.skip.reduce.max.skip.groups  0
cascading.flow.step.num 1
mapred.jobtracker.instrumentation   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerMetricsInst
mapr.localvolumes.path  /var/mapr/local
mapred.tasktracker.dns.nameserver   default
io.sort.factor  50
mapred.output.value.groupfn.class   cascading.tuple.hadoop.util.GroupingComparator
mapreduce.use.maprfs    true
mapred.task.timeout 600000
mapred.max.tracker.failures 4
hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory
mapred.mapoutput.key.class  cascading.tuple.io.TuplePair
fs.hdfs.impl    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
mapred.queue.default.acl-administer-jobs    
mapred.output.key.class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
mapred.skip.map.auto.incr.proc.count    true
mapred.map.runner.class cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowMapper
mapreduce.job.complete.cancel.delegation.tokens true
mapreduce.tasktracker.heapbased.memory.management   false
io.mapfile.bloom.size   1048576
tasktracker.http.threads    2
mapred.job.shuffle.merge.percent    0.70
cascading.flow.id   853276BF02049D394C31880B08C9E6CC
mapred.child.renice 10
fs.ftp.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem
user.name   jdavis
mapred.fairscheduler.smalljob.max.inputsize 10737418240
mapred.output.compress  false
io.bytes.per.checksum   512
mapred.healthChecker.script.timeout 600000
topology.node.switch.mapping.impl   org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping
mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps  0.95
mapred.reduce.max.attempts  4
fs.ramfs.impl   org.apache.hadoop.fs.InMemoryFileSystem
mapr.localoutput.dir    output
mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records    0
mapred.jobtracker.port  9001
mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb    -1
mapreduce.tasktracker.prefetch.maptasks 1.0
hadoop.security.group.mapping   org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
mapreduce.tasktracker.task.slowlaunch   false
mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.dir    /var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/jobsInfo
mapred.jar  /var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/staging/jdavis/.staging/job_201210022148_0086/job.jar
fs.s3.buffer.dir    ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/s3
job.end.retry.attempts  0
fs.file.impl    org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem
cascading.app.name  omeg
mapred.local.dir.minspacestart  0
mapred.output.compression.type  RECORD
fs.mapr.working.dir /user/$USERNAME/
fs.maprfs.impl  com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem
fs.https.impl   cascading.tap.hadoop.io.HttpFileSystem
topology.script.number.args 100
io.mapfile.bloom.error.rate 0.005
mapred.cluster.max.reduce.memory.mb -1
mapred.max.tracker.blacklists   4
mapred.task.profile.maps    0-2
mapred.userlog.retain.hours 24
mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.active false
hadoop.security.authorization   false
local.cache.size    10737418240
mapred.min.split.size   0
mapred.map.tasks    353
mapred.tasktracker.task-controller.config.overwrite true
cascading.app.appjar.path   /home/jdavis/tmp/omeg.jar
mapred.output.value.class   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
mapred.partitioner.class    cascading.tuple.hadoop.util.GroupingPartitioner
mapreduce.maprfs.use.compression    true
mapred.job.queue.name   default
mapreduce.tasktracker.reserved.physicalmemory.mb.low    0.90
cascading.group.comparator.size 3
ipc.server.listen.queue.size    128
group.name  common
mapred.inmem.merge.threshold    0
job.end.retry.interval  30000
mapred.fairscheduler.smalljob.max.maps  10
mapred.skip.attempts.to.start.skipping  2
fs.checkpoint.dir   ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/namesecondary
mapred.reduce.tasks 2
mapred.merge.recordsBeforeProgress  10000
mapred.userlog.limit.kb 0
mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb -1
webinterface.private.actions    true
io.sort.spill.percent   0.99
mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent 0.80
mapred.job.name [853276BF02049D394C31880B08C9E6CC/DCB7B555F1FC65C767B8E2CD716607AA] copyr/(1/1) /user/jdavis/ctest/end
mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution  false
hadoop.util.hash.type   murmur
mapred.map.max.attempts 4
mapreduce.job.acl-view-job

mapred.job.tracker.handler.count    10
mapred.input.format.class   cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputFormat
mapred.tasktracker.expiry.interval  600000
mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job  -1
mapred.jobtracker.job.history.block.size    3145728
keep.failed.task.files  false
mapred.output.format.class  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
ipc.client.tcpnodelay   false
mapred.task.profile.reduces 0-2
mapred.output.compression.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec
io.map.index.skip   0
mapred.working.dir  /user/jdavis
ipc.server.tcpnodelay   false
hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts 
mapred.reducer.class    cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowReducer
cascading.app.id    A593B4669179BB6F06771249E7ADFA48
mapred.used.genericoptionsparser    true
jobclient.progress.monitor.poll.interval    1000
mapreduce.tasktracker.jvm.idle.time 10000
mapred.job.map.memory.mb    -1
hadoop.logfile.size 10000000
mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution   false
mapreduce.job.dir   maprfs:/var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/staging/jdavis/.staging/job_201210022148_0086
mapreduce.tasktracker.outofband.heartbeat   true
mapreduce.reduce.input.limit    -1
mapred.tasktracker.ephemeral.tasks.ulimit   4294967296>
fs.s3n.block.size   67108864
fs.inmemory.size.mb 200
mapred.fairscheduler.smalljob.max.reducers  10
hadoop.security.authentication  simple
fs.checkpoint.period    3600
cascading.flow.step.id  DCB7B555F1FC65C767B8E2CD716607AA
mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks  -1
mapred.jobtracker.completeuserjobs.maximum  5
mapreduce.cluster.map.userlog.retain-size   10485760
mapred.task.tracker.task-controller org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LinuxTaskController
mapred.output.key.comparator.class  cascading.tuple.hadoop.util.GroupingSortingComparator
fs.s3.maxRetries    4
mapred.cluster.max.map.memory.mb    -1
mapred.mapoutput.value.class    cascading.tuple.Tuple
mapred.map.child.java.opts  -XX:ErrorFile=/opt/cores/mapreduce_java_error%p.log
mapred.job.tracker.history.completed.location   /var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/history/done
mapred.local.dir    /tmp/mapr-hadoop/mapred/local
fs.hftp.impl    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HftpFileSystem
fs.trash.interval   0
fs.s3.sleepTimeSeconds  10
mapred.submit.replication   10
fs.har.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.HarFileSystem
mapreduce.heartbeat.10  300
cascading.version   Concurrent, Inc - Cascading 2.0.5
mapred.map.output.compression.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec
mapred.tasktracker.dns.interface    default
hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups    root
mapred.job.tracker  maprfs:///
mapreduce.job.submithost    c10-m001.wowrack.upstream.priv
mapreduce.tasktracker.cache.local.numberdirectories 10000
io.seqfile.sorter.recordlimit   1000000
mapreduce.heartbeat.10000   100000
mapred.line.input.format.linespermap    1
mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FairScheduler
mapred.tasktracker.instrumentation  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerMetricsInst
mapred.tasktracker.taskmemorymanager.killtask.maxRSS    false
mapred.child.taskset    true
jobclient.completion.poll.interval  5000
mapred.fairscheduler.smalljob.max.reducer.inputsize 1073741824
mapred.local.dir.minspacekill   0
io.sort.record.percent  0.28
mapr.localspill.dir spill
io.compression.codec.lzo.class  com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec
fs.kfs.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.kfs.KosmosFileSystem
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum (CPUS > 2) ? (CPUS * 0.70): 1
mapred.temp.dir ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/temp
mapred.tasktracker.ephemeral.tasks.maximum  1
fs.checkpoint.edits.dir ${fs.checkpoint.dir}
mapred.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptime-before-sigkill   5000
mapred.job.reduce.input.buffer.percent  0.0
mapred.tasktracker.indexcache.mb    10
mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence    false
mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize    -1
hadoop.logfile.count    10
fs.automatic.close  true
mapred.skip.reduce.auto.incr.proc.count true
mapreduce.job.submithostaddress 10.100.0.99
mapred.child.oom_adj    10
io.seqfile.compress.blocksize   1000000
fs.s3.block.size    67108864
mapred.tasktracker.taskmemorymanager.monitoring-interval    3000
mapreduce.tasktracker.volume.healthcheck.interval   60000
mapred.cluster.ephemeral.tasks.memory.limit.mb  200
mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir   /var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/staging
mapred.acls.enabled false
mapred.queue.default.state  RUNNING
mapred.fairscheduler.smalljob.schedule.enable   false
mapred.queue.names  default
fs.hsftp.impl   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HsftpFileSystem
mapred.fairscheduler.eventlog.enabled   false
mapreduce.jobtracker.recovery.maxtime   480
mapred.task.tracker.http.address    0.0.0.0:50060
mapreduce.jobtracker.inline.setup.cleanup   false
mapred.reduce.parallel.copies   40
io.seqfile.lazydecompress   true
mapred.tasktracker.ephemeral.tasks.timeout  10000
mapred.output.dir   maprfs:/user/jdavis/ctest/end
mapreduce.tasktracker.group root
hadoop.workaround.non.threadsafe.getpwuid   false
io.sort.mb  512
mapred.reduce.child.java.opts   -Xmx12000m
ipc.client.connection.maxidletime   10000
mapred.compress.map.output  false
hadoop.security.uid.cache.secs  14400
mapred.task.tracker.report.address  127.0.0.1:0
mapred.healthChecker.interval   60000
ipc.client.kill.max 10
ipc.client.connect.max.retries  10
fs.http.impl    cascading.tap.hadoop.io.HttpFileSystem
fs.s3.impl  org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem
mapred.fairscheduler.assignmultiple true
mapred.user.jobconf.limit   5242880
mapred.input.dir    maprfs:/user/jdavis/ctest/mid
mapred.job.tracker.http.address 0.0.0.0:50030
io.file.buffer.size 131072
mapred.jobtracker.restart.recover   true
io.serializations   cascading.tuple.hadoop.TupleSerialization,org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization
mapreduce.use.fastreduce    false
mapred.reduce.copy.backoff  300
mapred.task.profile false
mapred.jobtracker.retiredjobs.cache.size    300
jobclient.output.filter FAILED
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum    (CPUS > 2) ? (CPUS * 0.80) : 1
io.compression.codecs   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
fs.checkpoint.size  67108864
cascading.sort.comparator.size  3
```

---

```
2012-10-02 19:30:50,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=SHUFFLE, sessionId=
2012-10-02 19:30:50,737 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2012-10-02 19:30:50,742 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: /proc/<pid>/status does not have information about swap space used(VmSwap). Can not track swap usage of a task.
2012-10-02 19:30:50,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@27b62aab
2012-10-02 19:30:50,903 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 9115 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:31:01,663 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 37 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:31:01,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 36 segments left of total size: 1204882102 bytes
2012-10-02 19:31:03,079 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 7596 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:31:15,487 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 4803 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:31:15,489 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 11069 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:33:37,821 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 20846 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:33:59,274 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 35 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:33:59,275 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 35 segments left of total size: 1176895576 bytes
2012-10-02 19:34:02,131 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 21791 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:34:29,927 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 22847 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:36:32,181 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 30438 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:37:18,243 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 3852 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:37:26,292 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 37 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:37:26,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 37 segments left of total size: 1233203028 bytes
2012-10-02 19:39:07,695 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 9813 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:39:10,764 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 10045 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:39:56,829 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 17383 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:40:18,295 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 19584 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:40:32,307 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 58 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:40:32,308 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 44 segments left of total size: 1206978885 bytes
2012-10-02 19:41:35,154 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 26361 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:43:53,644 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 56 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:43:53,645 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 56 segments left of total size: 1217287352 bytes
2012-10-02 19:46:55,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 44 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:46:55,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 44 segments left of total size: 1221163604 bytes
2012-10-02 19:49:57,894 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 85 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:49:57,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 62 segments left of total size: 1229975233 bytes
2012-10-02 19:52:09,914 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: The process 25247 may have finished in the interim.
2012-10-02 19:52:52,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:52:52,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 32065409 bytes
2012-10-02 19:52:53,327 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 8 sorted segments
2012-10-02 19:52:53,345 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 8 segments left of total size: 8522450575 bytes
2012-10-02 19:52:53,366 INFO cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowReducer: cascading version: Concurrent, Inc - Cascading 2.0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Well to part one of your question. Its not enough to give hadoop simply more memory and expect thats its using it and things get faster automatically (would be very nice though!).
But you need to adapt the configuration properties to make use of your memory. I.e. io.sort.mb is one setting which can help to speed up the merge/shuffle phase.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred-default.html is a list of most of the configuration properties.
http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf gives some explicit advice on speeding up the merge (Slide 15).

Enabling compression of intermediate output (mapred.compress.map.output) usually speed up things as well.

HTH
Johannes

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an answer on all questions, but I can explain, why so much data transferred.

CoGroup mark each key with tag of the originating input. So, if you data consists only of 2 keys, it easy to see, that data can be easily doubled in size (small key + tag of similar size). Thats gives you 17GB of data.

Next, 353 mappers each process 17mb (very small, do you have many small input files?, by default each mapper should recieve blocksize data (mapr don't expose it's size in job.xml, so don't know how big you block is), but in case of 64GB you should process this data with much smaller amount of mappers (~100).

I don't actually know how Mapr Direct Shuffle (tm) works  (right now investigating), but looks like mappers outputs was written/exposed to maprfs. So, shuffle/sort phase in reducer download those parts directly from maprfs. Thats gives us 17GB (you can sum all sizes in you reducer log). But from where additional 6GB appears - don't know. May be this question can be sent to mapr support.